# general formula to find the number of times an element at an index appears if we consider all contiguous sub arrays

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, logic

We have a list of number say {$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$} where $1$ is the first element of list ad $2$ is the second element i.e list is $1$ indexed .We write all the contiguous sub array of this array .How many times will element at index $1$ will appear and how many time index at element $2$ will appear in the contiguous subarray that we write ?
Eg. in list {$1$ $2$ $3$}, $1$ appears $3$, $2$ appears $4$ times and $3$ appears $3$ times.Is there any general formula to find this ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Yes, a subarray in a list $L$ with $l$ elements is determined by it's initial and final index (let's call them $a,b$) so if you want index $i$ to be in the array, you should have $a\leq i\leq b$ so you can pick, say $b$, in $n+1-i$ ways.
In how many ways can you pick $a$?
Then use the multiplication rule.
Hope it helps.